# get arraylist size from object using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class which I want to analyze with java.reflection.
I created a class that has an Arraylist of other object.
When I want to analyze class which has the ArrayList the class is recongized but I dont know how to get the Arraylist size.

I attached the code.

public class Department {
    private ArrayList Students;

```
public Department() {
    super();
    Students = new ArrayList<>();
}
public Department(ArrayList<Student> students) {
    super();
    Students = students;
}
public void addStudent(Student student){
    if(student != null){
        this.Students.add(student);
    }

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Class [Students=" + Students  + "]";
}


public static void analyze2(Object obj){
    Class c =  obj.getClass();
    Field[] fieldType= c.getDeclaredFields();
    ArrayList<?> ob = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(obj.toString());

      for(Field field : fieldType){
          Class cd = field.getType();
          ob = (ArrayList<?>) cd.cast(ob);
          System.out.println(field.getName()+" "+ field.getType());
          System.out.println(ob.size());

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get & invoke the `size` method via reflection without casting the object back to `ArrayList`, you can use `Method.invoke()`:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");

    Object obj = list;
    Class noparams[] = {};
    Class cls =  obj.getClass();

    // note may throw: NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException
    Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("size", noparams);
    method.setAccessible(true);

    // note may throw: IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,  InvocationTargetException
    Object retObj = method.invoke(obj, (Object[]) null);

    System.out.println(retObj);
```

I made a note of exceptions that need to be handled, but omitted exception handling specifics as it clutters the code & varies based on your specific context - do what's best for your situation.

Official tutorial: [method invocation via reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the field value using the `get` method and pass the instance of the `Department` object. If the field is of type `ArrayList`, then cast the result to an 'ArrayList' and then print its size.

```
  for(Field field : fieldType){
      Class<?> cd = field.getType();
      Object fieldVal = field.get(ob);
      if(fieldVal instanceof ArrayList){
         ArrayList<?> arrayListField = (ArrayList<?>)fieldVal;
         System.out.println(arrayListField.size());
      }
      System.out.println(field.getName()+" "+ field.getType());
  }
```